# SQL query for latest record in one-to-many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with establishing SQL query for statement which will count number of rows from one table:

```
ID       Date             Status_id     Parent_id
1        2012-1-1         2             1    
2        2012-3-21        1             2  
3        2012-3-6         1             1    
4        2012-6-11        1             3   
5        2012-1-7         2             1    
6        2012-1-5         1             3
```

statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM person 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2012-1-1' AND '2012-1-30' AND status_id=1
```

Gave me number `3` but in this amount are the rows with same parent, I want to have only unique parents to be counted and if there are two rows with same parent only the one with latest date counts. Can anyone give me a hint how I can improve the query to work like I described?

Comment: What RMDS are you using? (mysql, sql-server, oracel)

Comment: It should give you the number `0` because of the date.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL database

Comment: so max count per parent will be one right?

Comment: Have you tried the GROUP BY clause with the field Parent_id ? I'm not sure it will work but you can give a try.

Comment: @Fathah this is what I want to achieve i read about `UNION` function but it gave me syntax error..

Comment: i'll provide mysql query.... you can convert it to PostgreSQL right?

Comment: as long as you won't use any `mysql_` functions like, I see no problem in it

Comment: @Mithrand1r Your query is correct just replace `count(*)` with `count(distinct Parent_id)` Hope it helps...

Comment: @Meherzad your solution kinda work but I don't quite understand it. Does `distinct` allow me to choose how to select `unique` field? I mean if I have two the same `parent_id` I want to choose one with the latest date. It is really important for me

Comment: Distinct will count only unique parentId...  As you are only counting number of records within a date range it doesn't matter whether you take latest or other.

Comment: @Mithrand1r by the way how you are getting 3 for your above query? answer for above query is 1 right?

Comment: if it came to think about it more you are right, I can adjust it by improving my `where` section. Please Post your comment as Answer so I can mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(DISTINCT Parent_id) 
FROM 
   person 
WHERE 
   date BETWEEN '2012-1-1' AND '2012-1-30' AND 
   status_id=1
```

Hope it helps....